# Insertion in DB php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data in database .Here is my query that i printed using **echo**

```
INSERT INTO tablename(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,Cell#)VALUES('myname', 'myemail@yahoo.com', 'Pakistan','Lahore','refid',03001234567)
```

here is my query in php code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,Cell#)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$country','$city','$refId',$cellNo)";  
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $sql;
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
                                $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                                if(! $retval )
                                {
                                  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                                }
                                echo "Entered data successfully\n";
                                mysql_close($conn);
```

When I run,it gives me the following error.

> Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

Query looks correct to me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove # symbol from query. This is like comment after this symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `#` from your query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,Cell#)
                                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The # mark is used to comment in SQL, So in your query everything after the # becomes a comment ( at least in the particular line )

Removing the # would do the correction.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,Cell)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$country','$city','$refId',$cellNo)";  
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $sql;
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the column is `Cell#` then you must quote it so the `#` isn't treated as the start of a comment:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,`Cell#`)VALUES('myname', 'myemail@yahoo.com', 'Pakistan','Lahore','refid',03001234567)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ` before and after Cell# as shown in the below query

```
INSERT INTO tablename (
  NameOfVisitor, Email, Country,City,ReferenceID,`Cell#`) 
VALUES (
  'myname', 'myemail@yahoo.com', 'Pakistan','Lahore','refid',03001234567)
```

so your php code should be as below

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(NameOfVisitor, Email, Country, City, ReferenceID, `Cell#`) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$country', '$city', '$refId', $cellNo)";  
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    echo "Could not enter data: " . mysql_error();
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```